# Passing arguments from model to controller..Returns only one row

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
function supplypoint($salesDate)
{
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT(request_id),pos_no 
          FROM  outward 
          WHERE  outward_date =  '$salesDate'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $request_id = $row->request_id;
            echo "request_id:".$request_id;
            $pos_no = $row->pos_no;

            $sql1="SELECT shoppe_id FROM atm_store 
                   WHERE pos_id =  '$pos_no'";
            $query1 = $this->db->query($sql1);
            if($query1->num_rows>0)
            {
                $sql2="SELECT  A.`request_id`, A.`stock_id` , A.`pos_no` , 
                   B.amount, sum(A.`outward` * A.`price` ) AS total, A.`outward_date`
                   FROM `outward` A
                   INNER JOIN atm_franchisees B
                   INNER JOIN atm_store C
                   ON B.user_id = C.user_id AND A.pos_no = C.pos_id 
                   WHERE A.`outward_date`='$salesDate' 
                   AND A.`request_id`='$request_id'
                   GROUP BY A.`request_id`";
            }
            else
            {
                $sql2="SELECT  A.`request_id`, A.`stock_id` , A.`pos_no` , 
                   B.amount, sum(A.`outward` * A.`price` ) AS total, A.`outward_date`
                   FROM `outward` A
                   INNER JOIN atm_franchisees B
                   INNER JOIN atm_super_shoppe C ON B.user_id = C.user_id AND A.pos_no = C.pos_id 
                   WHERE A.`outward_date`='$salesDate' 
                   AND A.`request_id`='$request_id' 
                   GROUP BY A.`request_id`";
            }
       }
       $query2 = $this->db->query($sql2);
       return $query2;
    }
}
```

its returns only the first row? can u find the issue

Comment: There is only one record in the database that matches the query??

Comment: there are more than one ... its around ten records

Comment: Then I don't know. Good luck finding the answer.

Comment: can you tell us what exactly do you recieve in your controller ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of

```
$query1->num_rows > 0
```

Use :

```
$query1->num_rows() > 0
```

Then, try to return :

```
$query2 = $this->db->query($sql2);
return $query2->results();
```